# npm ERR! install electron-packager

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, electron-packager

I am creating a new electron app and now I need to install electron-packager in it.

node -v v10.16.0 & npm -v v6.9.0

(I updated both)

I have tried to run this:

```
npm install electron-packager --save-dev
```

and this:

```
npm install electron-packager -g
```

The Error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/electron-packager
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'electron-packager@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you specified the OS.
I once faced this problem and downgrading node to v8.0 fixed this problem.

But I would strongly recommend you to use electron-builder(https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) instead of electron-packager for creating installer packages, as it is a lot easier with lot more options including built-in auto-update feature.

Comment: It is a win32-x64...I think it could be because of the proxy. But I don't know how to install from behind a proxy.

Comment: What exactly you meant by proxy?

Comment: A corporate proxy of my company.